# How to use a variable for a file path? Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, variables, path

Is there the possibility in Ruby to use a variable / string to define a file path?

For example I would like to use the variable **location** as follow:

```
location = 'C:\Users\Private\Documents'

#### some code here ####
class Array
  def to_csv(csv_filename)
    require 'csv'
    CSV.open(csv_filename, "wb") do |csv|
      csv << first.keys # adds the attributes name on the first line
      self.each do |hash|
        csv << hash.values
      end
    end
  end
end

array = [{:color => "orange", :quantity => 3},
         {:color => "green", :quantity => 1}]

array.to_csv('location\FileName.csv')
```

Comment: Learn about [string interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html). Aside from this, the `String` class has a method `+` for concatinating strings. You can do something like `location+'\FileName.csv'`. Side note: I suggest that you use forward slashes instead of backslashes as a path separator. Sooner or later, the backslashes will bite you if you use them inside a double-quoted string and you forget to escape them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variable inside string, following way:

```rb
array.to_csv("#{location}\FileName.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use File.join, which accepts variables as arguments.

```
irb(main):001:0> filename = File.basename('/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb')
=> "ruby.rb"
irb(main):002:0> path     = '/home/gumby/work'
=> "/home/gumby/work"
irb(main):003:0> File.join(path, filename)
=> "/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb"
```

As noted above, if you start embedding slashes in your strings things may get unmanageable in future.